# SQL Server Return 1 Row Per Boat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically, what I want to do is join 4 tables together and return 1 row for each boat.

Table Layouts

**[Boats]**

```
id, date, section, raft
```

**[Photos]**

```
id, boatid, pthurl, purl
```

**[River_Company]**

```
id, sort, company, company_short
```

**[River_Section]**

```
id, section
```

Its very simple as far as structure, however, I've having the time of my life trying to get it to return only 1 row. No boat will ever be on the same day, the only thing that's messing this up is the photo table.

If you know a better way for it to return the record table for all the boats boats and only 1 photo from the photo table, please, please post it!!

**Desired Format**

```
boats.id, boats.date, river_company.company, river_section.section, photos.purl, photos.pthurl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically how joins work. Since `boats` and `photos` are in *one-to-many* relationships and you want *one-to-one*-like query, you need to explicitly express it with predicate. For example:

```
select b.*
from
  boats b
    inner join photos p
      on b.id = p.boatid
where p.id = (select max(id) from photos where boatid = b.id)
```

Comment: select b.*,p.*
from
  boats b
    inner join photos p
      on b.id = p.boatid
where p.id = (select max(id) from photos where boatid = b.id)

Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ID` column is the relation that you have designed:

```
SELECT Boats.* FROM Boats
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos on Photos.ID = 
            (
              SELECT TOP 1 Photos.ID FROM Photos 
                 INNER JOIN Boats ON Photos.BoatID = Boats.ID
            )
  INNER JOIN River_Company on River_Company.ID = Boats.ID
  INNER JOIN River_Section on River_Section.ID = Boats.ID
```

So basically, this will:

- Guarantee the maximum row count of 1. (It's a bit dirty, but fact is if you have more than one photo, more than one link will be returned otherwise)
- If there are no photo's, the boat will still be returned

Comment: What happens if there are say, 5 boats? Wont it still only return 1 row? I need it to return all 5 boats.

Comment: @Tyler - Ok, I've updated with what I think you're getting at. Please excuse syntax errors if there are any.

Comment: it doesnt return any rows. incarnate's sql worked great with some slight modification. Thank you thou!